# Run startup script with another user

Tags: linux, sudo, tomcat, su, sudoers

I have two users `user1` and `user2`. And tomcat has owenership of `user1` and started with `user1` only.
I need to make a rule for user2 such that `user2` can starts/stop tomcat but tomcat should always be started with `user1`.

I have tried following command

```
su -c "./catalina.sh start" user1
```

But this requires user1's password. Another thing that i have tried is entry in sudoers file :

```
user2 ALL=(user1) NOPASSWD: /opt/Tomcat/bin/startup.sh,/opt/Tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

[user2@DRWJHK bin]$ sudo /opt/Tomcat/bin/startup.sh
Sorry, user user2 is not allowed to execute '/opt/Tomcat/bin/startup.sh' as root on localhost.localdomain.
```

Still I am unable to start tomcat as user1. Please help me solving this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sudo, you need to pass the -u option. Try:

```
sudo -u user1 /opt/Tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

Comment: It requires user1's password. we cannot share the password with user2.